# .Net Core Minio - PutObjectAsync not work for file larger than 12 MB

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, minio

currently I'm using following code to perform save operation into minio bucket:

```
    public async Task SaveFileAsync(Stream stream, string fileName)
    {
        MinioClient client = InitClient();

        bool found = await client.BucketExistsAsync(bucketName);
        if (!found)
        {
            await client.MakeBucketAsync(bucketName);
        }
        var fileType = "application/octet-stream";
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await client.PutObjectAsync(bucketName, fileName, stream, stream.Length, fileType);
    }
```

The problem is when I'm trying to send files greater than 12MB - then I'm reciving following error for MinioClient.PutObjectAsync method:

```
MinIO API responded with message=The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Stack trace:

```
at Minio.MinioClient.ParseError(IRestResponse response) in /home/maxim/dev/minio-dotnet/Minio/MinioClient.cs:line 491\n   at Minio.MinioClient.<>c.<.ctor>b__81_0(IRestResponse response)
     in /home/maxim/dev/minio-dotnet/Minio/MinioClient.cs:line 75\n   at Minio.MinioClient.HandleIfErrorResponse(IRestResponse response, IEnumerable`1 handlers, DateTime startTime) 
    in /home/maxim/dev/minio-dotnet/Minio/MinioClient.cs:line 525\n   at Minio.MinioClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(IEnumerable`1 errorHandlers, IRestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    in /home/maxim/dev/minio-dotnet/Minio/MinioClient.cs:line 371\n   at Minio.MinioClient.PutObjectAsync(String bucketName, String objectName, String uploadId, Int32 partNumber, Byte[] data, Dictionary`2 metaData, Dictionary`2 
    sseHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/maxim/dev/minio-dotnet/Minio/ApiEndpoints/ObjectOperations.cs:line 497\n  
     at Minio.MinioClient.PutObjectAsync(String bucketName, String objectName, Stream data, Int64 size, String contentType, 
    Dictionary`2 metaData, ServerSideEncryption sse, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/maxim/dev/minio-dotnet/Minio/ApiEndpoints/ObjectOperations.cs:line 301\n
```

From application code, stream is a memory stream incoming from asp .net core controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync(int id, IFormFile file)
{
            var command = new MyApplicationCommand();
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                command.ContentStream = memoryStream;
                command.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                command.FileName = file.FileName;

                await mediator.Send(command); // command handler just call SaveFileAsync with provided parameters
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if your stream has a length (i.e. is seekable). I think I had the same error once before.... If the stream comes for example from an `IBrowserFile` (blazor project) you can use that to get the necessary stream information.

Comment: @RolandDeschain could you please explain it more ? As you can see in my code, currently stream is created by incoming IFormFile (using CoptyToAsync method) - should I use another method to create a stream ?

Comment: No, what I mean is, your stream has a property called `CanSeek`. If this bool returns `false` your  `stream.Length` will return 0 regardless of the actual length. This is then where the minio sdk will fail. If that is the case (which I think) you need to get the length from somewhere else. In your case, if you have a `IFormFile` this should give you the length of the file correctly

Comment: Another thing to note (althouth not related to your problem): Be careful when loading files into a memory stream. Memory is very limited and if the uploaded files are big, you will get an out of memory error. There is a detailed description on the asp.net docs (blazor in this case, but applies generally):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly

Comment: Does this similar question help?Solved by lower version of RestSharp. https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet/issues/336

Comment: I resolved problem by upgrading Minio library to the newest version